# Box-shadow of div over inner div

Tags: html, css

I have an outer `div` with `box-shadow` and I want this to appear over an inner `div`. But it always appears under it. The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/q2Ltvz6u/).

My HTML is:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="inner">

  </div>

</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  box-shadow: inset 40px 0 10px -10px #bbbbbb;
}

.inner{
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Is it possible to get it so that the `box-shadow` appears over the inner blue `div`? The semantics of the HTML cannot change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the position of the child to relative and the z-index to -1:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px grey solid;
  box-shadow: inset 40px 0 10px -10px #bbbbbb;
}

.inner {
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="inner">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

update the styles of inner class with position absolute and give `z-index: -1;`;

```
.inner {
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Here is the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3pfvd1m/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are wanting without the inner container as well.

http://codepen.io/creativenauts/pen/rLWZqp

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  background-color: lightblue;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px rgba(#000, 0.5);
  position: relative;
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    box-shadow: inset 40px 0 10px -10px #bbbbbb;
  }
}
```